# Underscore/Lodash - Object from parent/children

Tags: recursion, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to create a formatted collection from one I get from a database (Mongo).

Here's the input's format :

```
[{_id:1,name:'1'},
 {_id:2,name:'2},
 {_id:3,name:'1-1',parent:1},
 ...
 {_id:50,name:'1-1-3',parent:3}]
```

As you can see, the 'deepest ancestors' are _ids 1 and 2. The first node of children contains _id 3, which has a child, _id 50.

I'm struggling to create this kind of collection, using Lodash :

```
[{
    _id:1,name:'1',children:[
        {_id:3,name:'1-1',children:[
            ...,
            {_id:50,name:'1-1-3',children:[]}
        ]},
        ...
    ]
},{
    _id:1,name:'1',children:[...]
}]
```

Here's what I've tried :

```
var result=_.chain(input)
    .groupBy('parent')
    .pairs()
    .map(function(currentItem){
        return _.object(_.zip(['parent','children'],currentItem))
    })
    .value();
```

But it doesn't work in a recursive way...

Is someone able to help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the collection to get the required structure:

```
// create and indexed object with the _id field as key - improve performance
var indexed = _.indexBy(data, '_id');

// iterate to create the structure
_.each( data, function(datum){
   datum.children = [];
   if( _.has(datum,'parent')){
      indexed[datum.parent].children.push(datum);
    }
})
```

This solution does assume that a parent is processed before each child i.e. the children array is created before it's pushed into. A number of ways to solve if needs be but the above code shows the way to create the nested structure.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the indexBy.
I've added the following code to keep only the deepest parents and have the structure I've wanted :
`_.map(data,function(d){if(!('parent' in d)){finalArray.push(d);};});`